# python subprocess send stout on the fly when running

Tags: python, process, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Is there a way to **child.py** sends stout "on the fly", when running?
Or **main.py** needs to wait **child.py** to terminate?

In these scripts, **main.py** needs to wait 5 seconds to start printing all lines.
I want that `process.stdout.readline()` get the last `print` in **child.py** when **child.py** still running.

**main.py**

```py
import subprocess
import time
process = subprocess.Popen(["./child.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
i = 1
while i < 5:
  print(process.stdout.readline()) #to print, child.py needs to terminate before
  time.sleep(1)
  i+=1
```

**child.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8

import sys
import time

def run():
  i = 1
  while i < 5:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'ok {i}')
    i+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In child.py you wrote this:

```
    print(f'ok {i}')
```

Replace it with this:

```
    print(f'ok {i}', flush=True)
```

---

When testing  interactively isatty() returns True,
so child.py will default to unbuffered behavior.
Each line of output will appear immediately.

When running as a subprocess connected to a pipe,
you are seeing it default to buffered behavior.
Use a flush() call to defeat this.